# ADFS 3.0 oAuth oauth2/token -> no registered protocol

Tags: oauth, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I'm trying to use the oAuth functionality of adfs but are struggling to get an access token out of it.
The setup is a  Windows Server 2012 R2 Preview Edition installed in a virtualbox vm.

I am able to get an access_code by issuing the following:

```
https://asdf.bla.dev/adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abcd-abcd-abcd&redirect_uri=https://localhost/auth&resource=testservice.asdf.oauth
```

this redirects me to the following url

```
https://localhost/auth?code=U2dIhBsRt0eDnEhAEq2fcw.d3LeME__0QgBAC8zvLR6mTlRvC0.fLKd5eQRjXslTEeEck17m6Zo4fKKO9oGk2byUyr4CyLQHKSJs5wKzWZcusLXqXk22tdzvswxBjzaYcCqzkbeT5VxhMEdq97vbSnGAQ1tVD0vutVIfbx1Mb5A-QItgOx8a8LBapn7axCpGThoVH2jWCVM59X5eOt9ACuJTTK1UFbNaldaTkuGdqrtcGC8tFoSOP96G-4sHgIBpi2t8BSwCdf3asDd3AJAOYk6gnUkH5WJQRf2pg4S_AkgOxseeZW8Y5qbWAajyESkEmJ-UcWkV98uHlrmNsFwTSJ-ZoNk-aZI_U85ZlZrsdpKzocrWM5HmfcvXm5XdXz2QXIHngIBTA
```

but when I try to redeem the token with this request:

```
https://asdf.bla.dev/adfs/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=abcd-abcd-abcd&redirect_uri=https://localhost/auth&code=U2dIhBsRt0eDnEhAEq2fcw.d3LeME__0QgBAC8zvLR6mTlRvC0.fLKd5eQRjXslTEeEck17m6Zo4fKKO9oGk2byUyr4CyLQHKSJs5wKzWZcusLXqXk22tdzvswxBjzaYcCqzkbeT5VxhMEdq97vbSnGAQ1tVD0vutVIfbx1Mb5A-QItgOx8a8LBapn7axCpGThoVH2jWCVM59X5eOt9ACuJTTK1UFbNaldaTkuGdqrtcGC8tFoSOP96G-4sHgIBpi2t8BSwCdf3asDd3AJAOYk6gnUkH5WJQRf2pg4S_AkgOxseeZW8Y5qbWAajyESkEmJ-UcWkV98uHlrmNsFwTSJ-ZoNk-aZI_U85ZlZrsdpKzocrWM5HmfcvXm5XdXz2QXIHngIBTA
```

there is an error and I don't get an access-token.

The event viewer of the adfs service states the following error:

*There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token to process the incoming request....*

I built the request following this information: https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Authorization-Code-grant-in-ADFS

I have no idea what's going wrong and would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

I know that the thread is quite old but I was going through hell today when trying to resolve this error. I checked http.sys, reinstalled the server role,... nothing worked.

At the end, I had to find out that this crazy ADFS does (again) return garbage error messages. After 5 hours of debugging I didn't trust postman any longer (even if it worked without issues for months now) and used a short PowerShell script to invoke the POST with the access code:

```
$client = new-object net.webclient

$form = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$form.Add("client_id", "you client id")
$form.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
$form.Add("code", "authorization code")
$form.Add("redirect_uri", "your redirect uri")

$result = $client.UploadValues("https://sso.mydomain.com/adfs/oauth2/token", "POST", $form)
$decodedToken = $client.Encoding.GetString($result);
```

Et voila... all working. So I went back to the broken postman query, stripped all url parameters, removed all headers and added the parameters to the x-www-form-urlencoded tab. Then it worked there again.

Meaningful errors would definitely be helpful. Hope this saves someone many hours of frustrating try&error...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You get code on redirect URI. Now we will have  to make a POST request to the `/token` endpoint using the following parameters:

- `code` - you will have to extract this value from the URL using some programming logic
- `client_id`
- `redirect_uri`
- `grant_type` - use the value "authorization_code"

In response you should get a JWT access token.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use HTTP GET to access the token endpoint, but it should be HTTP POST.

Comment: Assuming that the parameter values are also properly URL encoded  (esp. the value for `redirect_uri`), it looks like it is something configuration related on the server side, sorry. You could try and add a trailing slash to the token endpoint URL.

Comment: Do you have any idea what to look for on the server side?